# An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER ]

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I'm using phone authentication, it was working fine but after a couple of log in logout attempt its showing this error An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER ] and getting no verification code. i've inserted all gradle files google json file and also enabled the authentication in firebase console. It was working fine on the beginning but now showing weired error, i can only enter with whitelist number now

my build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devlearn.sohel.tkash"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:circular-progress-bar:1.2.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my logincode:

```
package com.devlearn.sohel.tkash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.devlearn.sohel.tkash.Models.UserDetails;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edtPhone;
    private EditText edtName;
    private TextView txtMessege;
    private RelativeLayout rootlayout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnLogin;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;

    public String phoneNumber;
    public String userName;
    private String mVerificationId;
    public SpotsDialog waitingDialog;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

//    ctrl+o
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.SplashThme);
        //before setcontentview
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Ubuntu.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        edtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
        edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        txtMessege = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMessege);
        rootlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                phoneNumber = edtPhone.getText().toString();
                userName = edtName.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber))
                {
                    edtPhone.setError("Incorrect phone number format");
                    requestFocus(edtPhone);
                }
                else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userName))
                {
                    edtName.setError("Please insert your name");
                    requestFocus(edtName);
                }
                else
                {
                    phoneNumber = edtPhone.getText().toString();

                    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                            String error = e.getMessage();
                            Snackbar.make(rootlayout, "Error "+e, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            Log.d("Error fire",error);
                            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // Invalid request
                                // ...
                                String erro = e.getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "error"+ erro, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d("Error fire",erro);
                            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                                // ...
                                String err = e.getMessage();
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "error"+ err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d("Error fire",err);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                            mVerificationId = verificationId;
                            mResendToken = token;

//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                            // ...
                        }
                    };
                    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                            phoneNumber,
                            60,
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                            LoginActivity.this,
                            mCallbacks
                    );

                    LoginUisngPhone();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void LoginUisngPhone() {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Verification");
//        dialog.setMessage("Please provide verification Code");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View layout_verification = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_verification,null);

        final EditText edtVerificationCode = layout_verification.findViewById(R.id.edtVerificationCode);
        final TextView txtCountdown = layout_verification.findViewById(R.id.txtCountdown);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = layout_verification.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                txtCountdown.setText("Please provide Verificatin Code sec remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                txtMessege.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorcolor));
                txtMessege.setText("Please wait for "+ millisUntilFinished / 1000+" sec to try Again");
                btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
                edtName.setEnabled(false);
                edtPhone.setEnabled(false);

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                txtCountdown.setText("Please Try Again!");
                txtMessege.setText("A verification Code will be sent when you click send verification");
                btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
                edtName.setEnabled(true);
                edtPhone.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }.start();

        dialog.setView(layout_verification);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                dialog.dismiss();

                //disable sign in button while processing
//                btnLogin.setEnabled(false);

                //validate the data
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtVerificationCode.getText().toString())) {
//                    edtVerificationCode.setError("Enter verification Code");
//                    requestFocus(layout_verification.findViewById(R.id.edtVerificationCode));
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Insert Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    String verificationCode = edtVerificationCode.getText().toString();

                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, verificationCode);
                    //dot waitng process
//                    waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(LoginActivity.this);
//                    waitingDialog.show();

                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
//                    waitingDialog.dismiss();
                }



            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
//                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            //dot waitng process
//                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success! checking user exists or not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            checkUserExists();
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                Snackbar.make(rootlayout, "Invalid " + error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                                Log.d("Error fire2",error);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void checkUserExists() {
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null)
        {
            final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

            mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Welcome!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
//                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,AccountSetupActivity.class);
//                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//                        startActivity(intent);
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("userName").setValue(userName);
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("userPhone").setValue(phoneNumber);
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("currentBalance").setValue(0.0);
                        mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).child("totalBalance").setValue(0.0);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {



                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos i updated the implementations just now but still getting same error [missing client identifier]

Comment: update google-services classpath too, try to copy paste both my code and then rebuild your project and run should work

Answer (score 1):

At last i solved the issue, it was because i tried and tested to many times using same device with my wifi network as well as mobile network. So somehow they blocked the request for this client id. As soon as i tried it in different device with different network everything was fine.
thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try to update app grandle like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devlearn.sohel.tkash"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:circular-progress-bar:1.2.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And project grandle like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @Sohel Mahmud is this help you?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

Comment: Download the json file again and put it in your project. Can I also see the changed code?

Comment: yes i redownloaded the json file but when i try to log in getting An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER ] also updated my code above

Comment: Please make sure your have enabled `Phone authentication` in your Firebase Console. Is not enabled right? Please enable it!

Comment: im working with phone authentication, why i'll not enable it? if its disable the error messege is different.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project from scratch?

Comment: im going to be mad soon, just started a new project and still getting same error!!! phone authentication was working fine for the past 3 days and my project is almost 70% finished. :(