# I am facing an issue with phone auth. The phone auth is working fine in development, but throwing an error when in test flight build

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

When I am clicking for  generating OTP with signinwithphonenumber() method. Firebase returns "Error: An internal error has occurred." this error in some iOS devices. While in development it is working fine. But test flight build returns this error in some devices and working fine with other device. I have done coding in react-native.Can anyone please help me resolving this issue? It would be a great help.
Thank you.

Comment: maybe related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984465/2083099

Comment: Thank you nima but the device in which I am getting issue, didn't requested before from that device

Comment: This issue is resolved.now

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help